# Кривой перевод в истории проверок

Tags: обсуждение, статус-завершено, локализация

Проблема с переводом в [истории проверок запоздалых ответов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/history):

[image: Вы ещё не проверяли ни одной запоздалые ответы.]

А так же в истории проверок предлагаемых правок:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А у вас пока нет учетной записи в Transifex/

Comment: @NickVolynkin чего нет, того нет. Но я вот уже собрался почитать про [это](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1032/%d0%9a%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%89%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это составное сообщение, которое выглядит следующим образом

> You have not reviewed any $QueueTitle$ yet.

Поправил на следующий вариант:

> Вы еще не проверяли ни одного сообщения из очереди «запоздалые ответы»